# Is a r.v. supported on $\mathbb Q$ discret or continuous ? Same question for $\mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$.

Tags: probability

- I know that a discret r.v. is a r.v. that is supported on a finite set or a countable set. But if $X$ is s.t. $\mathbb P\{X\in\mathbb Q\}=1$, how should I right the expected value :
  $$\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{x\in\mathbb Q}x\mathbb P\{X=x\}$$
  or $$\mathbb E[X]=\int_{\mathbb Q}x f_X(x)dx\ \ ?$$
  The sum doesn't has sense for me, so I would say that the integral is the correct formulae. But if it is, is really $X$ a discrete r.v. ?
- Same question if $\mathbb P\{X\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q\}=1$. To me s.t. a r.v. is not continuous, but is not continuous as well. So what can it be ?

Comment: The integral is not the right expression, since $f_X$ wouldn't exist for a discrete random variable. It could be $\int_{\mathbb{Q}}xdP$, which is the same as the summation that you wrote.

Comment: Just to clarify. The definition of a [continuous random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) is one for which there is a function $f_X$ such that $dP(x)=f_X(x)dx$. So, if your random variable is discrete, and in particular not-continuous, then such $f_X$ cannot exist.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with the sum. It looks strange because you don't usually think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as being well ordered, but that's just a small flaw. For the sum to make sense you will of course need it to converge absolutely and then it will converge independently of how you choose the well ordering of $\mathbb{Q}$.

(re.: acetone's comment) The definition of the expected value for a countably infinitely supported r.v. contains the requirement that the sum converge absolutely.

As to the second question in the OP. You don't point out what the probability space here is or what $\mathbb{P}$ is and for continuous random variables that is quite important.

But for example take $X$ a continuous random variable with a normal distribution on the reals. Then $\mathbb{P}(\{X\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\})=1$ will be true since $\mathbb{Q}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Again following from helpful comments by acetone:

Continuous random variable might be the part that's confusing you OP. Depending on what your definition of that term is you get very different results. In general you have discrete random variables (those are on probability spaces with finite or countably infinite many elements), continuous random variables those have a continuous probability distribution function (usually we think of them as having values in some subset of the reals with the corresponding borel $\sigma$-algebra as the measurable sets), and then there the "other" random variables.

Sometimes the "other" random variables get lumped up into the continuous random variables because they are not discrete and we think of the underlying sets (Reals, Complex numbers) as being continuous in some sense but that leads to confusion.

Comment: If the expectation exists (the Lebesgue integral exists) then it converges absolutely by definition.

Comment: @acetone I don't really much see the point in looking at the Lebesgue integral. While you certainly can do it that way I think the approach through summation is quite reasonable. And yes in that case the definition of the expected value is defined iff the sum converges absolutely which is what I was trying to say. I may try to reword it so it is more obvious it's a result of a definition rather than just me making it up.

Comment: The rewording that you will get from the definition of Lebesgue integral is: The expected value exists when the sum for $x\geq 0$ converges and the sum for $x<0$ converges. That is the definition of Lebesgue integral for functions of arbitrary sign. See now the point of bringing it up? Clarity.

Comment: @acetone But you don't generally define the expected value for a discrete random variable using the Lebesgue integral. In some cases it's actually super counter intuitive since you don't normally think of $\mathbb{N}$ as a measurable space. And that's where you will have most discrete infinitely supported random variables.

Comment: Well. We are not in Kansas anymore. But even in $\mathbb{N}$ the definition is the same, absolute convergence $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x|P(X=x)<\infty$ is assumed.

Comment: @acetone Yeap agreed. I think there is also some confusion in terms of what a "continuous random variable" is. Since I've certainly seen it used for all random variables which are not discrete, but that's not the same as the continuous you linked in your comment to the OP's post. That comment assumes the probability distributions function is continuous. The general definition of random variable allows for fairly crazy random variables. You just need a pair of $\sigma$-algebras and you're good to go.

Comment: I have seen it too. Take into account that the name likely predates the modern integration theory. Beyond the name, what is more important is to know [Lebesgue decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_decomposition_theorem). Discrete probabilities will be equal to their singular part, and whether you allow continuous ones to have singular part or not, is up to you.

Comment: Some comments: "You don't point out what the probability space here is or what ℙ is and for continuous random variables that is quite important." Actually, whether for discrete or non discrete random variables, the choice of a specific probability space is quite irrelevant. "discrete random variables (those are on probability spaces with finite or countably infinite many elements)" No, discrete random variables can, and are often, defined on uncountable probability spaces. "Sometimes the "other" random variables get lumped up into..." Why the mystery? Every ...

Comment: ... distribution on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ has **three** parts: an absolutely continuous part (described by  a density), an atomic part (aka a sum of Dirac masses), and a singular part (none of the above, that is, with no atom and no density).

Comment: @did Feel free to write a better answer please. I'm certainly not a probability theorist. I'm looking at it from the point of view of someone that has only taken a few intro probability courses at university and that was a long while ago.

Comment: What I wrote suffices amply to correct your post.